# Create unique DataFrames by name from list of .csv's

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create pandas DataFrames from a list of read_csv objects using the following code.While creating the DataFrame I would like to also rename the newly created DataFrame by replacing the '_data' with '_df'

```
test_data = pd.read_csv('test/path'/.csv')
train_data = pd.read_csv('train/path'/.csv')
example_data = pd.read_csv('example/path'/.csv')
more_data = pd.read_csv('more/path'/.csv')

data_list = [test_data, train_data, example_data, more_data]

for i in data_list:
    pd.DataFrame(i).rename(i.replace('_data', '_df'))
```

However the above does not work as I receive this error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: Are you trying to rename the variable names? test_data to test_df?

Comment: test/pat.csv has one column,wright?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a pandas DataFrame from the test_data object (read_csv) and rename the DataFrame by replacing the '_data' with '_df'.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary to rename, with keys being current column name, and the value being the new name you want

```
pd.DataFrame(data_list).rename({columns={'test_data':'test_df', 'train_data':'train_df'})
```

or just a list with all names you want:

```
df.columns = ['test_df','train_df']
```

Answer (score 0):

`rename` accepts callable for the entire DataFrame. You don't have to iterate on the columns one by one. Pandas provides that for you.

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace('data','df'))
```

Pay attention this operation does not happen in place thus needs to be assigned to a variable or be given the `inplace` argument, although this is not considered a best practice.

```
test_data = pd.read_csv('test/path'/.csv')
train_data = pd.read_csv('train/path'/.csv')
example_data = pd.read_csv('example/path'/.csv')
more_data = pd.read_csv('more/path'/.csv')

data_list = [test_data, train_data, example_data, more_data]

for i in data_list:
    i.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace('data','df'), inplace=True)
```